# Password shown twice for django register form

Tags: python, django

I am making django register form, but it shows the password twice. (three times including password conformation)

[image]

Does anyone figure out the reason>

These are source code below.

register.html

```
{% extends "defapp/base.html" %}
{% block title %}User Register{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

RegisterView Class

```
class RegisterView(CreateView):
    form_class = f.RegisterForm
    template_name = "defapp/register.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("top")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        self.object = user
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

class Login(LoginView):
    form_class = f.LoginForm
    template_name = 'defapp/login.html'


class Logout(LoginRequiredMixin, LogoutView):
    template_name = 'defapp/login.html'
```

RegisterForm is here.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm,UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            field.widget.attrs['placeholder'] = field.label   


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "password", "email"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django already provides `password` field by default in the `UserCreationForm`, so you don't need to add `password` in the `RegisterForm` fields.

```py
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email"]
```

you can customize it like this...

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Confirm-Password'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2',]
        widgets = {
            'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter User Name'}),
            'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Enter E-Mail'}),
        }
```